# How to access method from one GameObject to another on google OnAdclosed on Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I have a GameScreenManger that will show or hide a panel based on the game status. I have a AdManager gameObject that holds a script that handles ads. I am able to show the ad, but on onAdclosed if i tried to make a reference of GameScreenManager that holds a script in Admanager Script and call a function when onAdclosed event listeners function, the call is triggering, but the actions are not working. Could some one help me in this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static AdManager instance;

    private string appId = "";

    private InterstitialAd InterstitialAd;
    private string InterstitialAdId = "interstitial_Ad_Id";


    private RewardedAd RewardedVideoAd;
    private string RewardedVideoAdId = "rewarded_video_ad_Id ";

    public GameObject RewardPanel;
    public GameScreenManager gameManager;

    public bool isRewardedVideo;

    private bool RewardedVideoLoaded = false;

    public void Awake()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            instance = this;
        } else
        {
            Destroy(this);
        }

        MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        RequestInterstitial();

        RewardedVideoAd = new RewardedAd(RewardedVideoAdId);

        RequestRewardedVideo();

        // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
        this.RewardedVideoAd.OnAdLoaded += HandleRewardedAdLoaded;

        // Called when an ad request failed to load.
        this.RewardedVideoAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad;

        // Called when an ad is shown.
        this.RewardedVideoAd.OnAdOpening += HandleRewardedAdOpening;

        // Called when an ad request failed to show.
        this.RewardedVideoAd.OnAdFailedToShow += HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow;

        // Called when the user should be rewarded for interacting with the ad.
        this.RewardedVideoAd.OnUserEarnedReward += HandleUserEarnedReward;

        // Called when the ad is closed.
        this.RewardedVideoAd.OnAdClosed += HandleRewardedAdClosed;

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (RewardedVideoLoaded == false)
        {
            RequestRewardedVideo();
        }
    }

    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        string adUnitId = InterstitialAdId;

        // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
        this.InterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the interstitial with the request.
        this.InterstitialAd.LoadAd(request);
    }

    public void ShowInterstitial()
    {
        if (this.InterstitialAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            this.InterstitialAd.Show();
        }
    }

    public void RequestRewardedVideo()
    {
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the interstitial with the request.
        this.RewardedVideoAd.LoadAd(request);

        if (this.RewardedVideoAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            isRewardedVideo = true;
            RewardedVideoLoaded = true;
        } else
        {
            isRewardedVideo = false;
            RewardedVideoLoaded = false;
        }
    }

    public void ShowRewardedVideo()
    {
        if (this.RewardedVideoAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            this.RewardedVideoAd.Show();
        }
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardedAdLoaded event received");
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print(
            "HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad event received with message: "
                             + args.Message);
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdOpening(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardedAdOpening event received");
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print(
            "HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow event received with message: "
                             + args.Message);
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardedAdClosed event received");

        Debug.Log("{lo} OnClosed called sender = " + sender);

        RequestRewardedVideo();

        gameManager.CheckForLives(); //This is not working.

        this.RewardPanel.SetActive(true);

    }

    public void HandleUserEarnedReward(object sender, Reward args)
    {

        Debug.Log("{lo} Earned a Reward  HandleUserEarnedReward called!");

        string type = args.Type;
        double amount = args.Amount;
        this.RewardPanel.SetActive(true);

    }
}
```

GameScreen Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameScreenManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PauseScreen;
    public GameObject OutOfLifeScreen;
    public GameObject PauseButton;
    public GameObject Scoretext;
    public GameObject Livesbutton;

    public Text MusicText;

    public void LoadPause()
    {
        PauseScreen.SetActive(true);
        bool audioPlaying = FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().audioPlaying;

        MusicText.text = audioPlaying ? "MUSIC ON" : "MUSIC OFF";
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
    }

    public void ShowResume()
    {
        PauseScreen.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
    }

    public void ShowMainMenu()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
    }

    public void ShowOutOfLives()
    {
        OutOfLifeScreen.SetActive(true);
        PauseButton.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;

    }

    public void CloseOutOfLives()
    {

       Debug.Log(" {lo} Entered CloseOutOfLives");
       OutOfLifeScreen.SetActive(false);
       PauseButton.SetActive(true);
       Time.timeScale = 1f;
    }

    public void TogggleSound()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().ToggleMute();
        bool audioPlaying = FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().audioPlaying;

        MusicText.text = audioPlaying ? "MUSIC ON" : "MUSIC OFF";
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("audioNeeded", audioPlaying ? 1 : 0);
    }

    public void Quit()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: your provided `GameScreenManager` script doesn't have any method called `CheckForLives` ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the callbacks are coming from a non-main thread, and unity is a single threaded environment, so some unity APIs are inaccessible from non-main threads, for example you can't use GameObject.SetActive or many more component functions except from the main thread, so what you need to do is dispatch the callback to the main thread first, then all statements in your function will execute.

Here's how.

1) A simple dispatcher that executes methods on unity's main thread.
create an empty game object in your scene, and attach this to it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// <summary>
/// Helps dispatch task results to the main thread to be able to operate on unity's API like SetActive, enabled etc...
/// </summary>
public class MainThreadDispatcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    Queue<Action> jobs = new Queue<Action>();
    static MainThreadDispatcher Instance = null;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        while (jobs.Count > 0)
        {
            var next = jobs.Dequeue();
            if(next != null)
            {
                next.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Dispatches a function to be executed on unity's main thread to be able to use unity's API.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newJob"></param>
    public static void Dispatch(Action newJob)
    {
        if (newJob == null)
            return;
        Instance.jobs.Enqueue(newJob);
    }
}
```

2) Edit your on ad closed callback to dispatch to the main thread.

```
    public void HandleRewardedAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // simply give unity control back.
        // you can pick and choose to execute what on main thread,
        // but I'm just gonna dispatch the whole block.
        MainThreadDispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
        {
            MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardedAdClosed event received");

            Debug.Log("{lo} OnClosed called sender = " + sender);

            RequestRewardedVideo();

            gameManager.CheckForLives();

            this.RewardPanel.SetActive(true);
        });
    }
```

Comment: One small thing, could you correct this line, removing (?) [ jobs.Dequeue()?.Invoke();]

Comment: It checks if the task to dispatch next is null before invoking it, so even if for some reason the task is disposed, it doesn't throw an exception when  trying to invoke, I'll correct it to work with projects using .Net 3.5 and those with .Net 4.x

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have a reference to your object in the second script:

Ad Script

```c
public GameScreenManager gsmanagerRef; //drag and drop on the editor or find it on initialization
```

then you should be able to call

```c
gsmanagerRef.ShowResume(); //or any other function
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: if i call like this, i get a log at the desired function, but the startements in that functions are not triggering.
For example:
gameManager.ShowResume() calls this function 

public void ShowResume() {
  Debug.Log("Coming Here");
  Time.timescale = 1f; // This not working
}
Any context needed?

Comment: There is probably something else that is setting the timescale to 0. The log appearing is a signal that the call to the function worked.

Comment: Even if i tried to set a panel object to show(somePanel.SetActive(true)), that too is not working?

Comment: @GameKeeper could it be you are doing something in FixedUpdate()? Or could it be you have some other behavior? Try adding a breakpoint to your function and watching the execution to debug your problem.

Comment: Please check my answer guys, hope it makes sense!

Comment: This functionality is not working only if i call the function from the event listener functions.(onAdClosed) from abmob. if I call it inside any of the normal Admanager functions, its working perfect. I was wondering any context reference needed for the ad listener functions?